# Finding the Maximum and Minimum using a Group By and a Join statement

Tags: sql, oracle

There are 3 tables in my database. Order, Item and Order_has_item created by many to many relationship between orders and items.

[image]

What I need to do is get `order_ids` of orders during a specific time period and then get the `items` related to that set of orders from `order_has_item`.   I must then get the count of `qty` (quantities) of the items by grouping them using `item_id` and then find the items sold maximum and minimum times.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT a.item_id,sum(a.qty) 
FROM order_has_item a 
FULL OUTER JOIN order b ON a.order_id = b.order_id 
WHERE TO_CHAR(b.datetime, 'MON') = 'JAN'
GROUP BY a.item_id 
ORDER BY sum(a.quantity);
```

What am I missing? I tried using a `having` clause but it won't work.

**-UPDATE-**

[image]

A sample output. I need to take the Maximum and Minimum results from Total Quantity. So Maximum should be Item Id 1 and 45 and the Minimum should be Item ID 62

Comment: Sample data and expected output would help ensure that others are understanding your question correctly.

Comment: Where does the `quantity` column comes from (it cannot be seen in the picutre of the schema)? Should we assume that it comes from table `item`?

Comment: So my bad. I will fix it. it's qty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic of your query does not seem right : why self-`FULL OUTER JOIN` the `order` table?

Here is a simple aggregate query that `JOIN`s `order` and `order_has_item` and return the total quantity for each item, within the given time frame:

```
SELECT ohi.item_item_id, SUM(ohi.qty) total_qty
FROM order o
INNER JOIN order_has_item ohi ON ohi.order_order_id = o.oder_id
WHERE 
    o.datetime >= TO_DATE('2019-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
    o.datetime <  ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('2019-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 1)
GROUP BY ohi.item_id
```

I changed the condition on the timeframe to avoid the use of `TO_CHAR()` on the left side of the comparison, because this construct basically defeats an existing index on column `datetime`.

Now if you are looking to select the items with the highest and lowest total quantity over the period, you can use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
        x.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY total_qty) rn_asc,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY total_qty DESC) rn_desc
    FROM (
        SELECT ohi.item_item_id, SUM(ohi.qty) total_qty
        FROM order o
        INNER JOIN order_has_item ohi ON ohi.order_order_id = o.oder_id
        WHERE 
            o.datetime >= TO_DATE('2019-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
            o.datetime <  ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('2019-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 1)
        GROUP BY ohi.item_id
    ) x
) y WHERE rn_asc = 1 OR rn_desc = 1
```

---

If even top records exist (ie more than one item have the maximum or minimum quantity), you can use `RANK()` instead of `ROW_NUMBER()` to display all of them.

Comment: Great!, but there's a problem. I ran it. In a case where there are 2 or more maximums or minimums, output only shows 1 item.  I need all the maximums and minimums;

Comment: @StarLord: I see. In this case, you can use `RANK()` instead of `ROW_NUMBER()`

Comment: @StarLord:  sure. `RANK()` assigns a row number to each record, sorted by `total_qty`. So whit `ORDER BY total_qty`, record(s) with the lowest `total_qty` get rank `1` (that's `rn_asc`). On the other hand, `ORDER BY total_qty DESC`, record(s) with the higest `total_qty` get rank `1` (`rn_desc`).

Answer (score 0):

I've never used full outer join. This may work

`SELECT * FROM (SELECT *,  MAX(CountItems) AS maxItems, MIN(CountItems) AS minItems FROM (
SELECT ohi.item_id, sum(ohi.qty) AS [CountItems] FROM order o 
JOIN order_has_item ohi ON o.order_id=ohi.order_id where TO_CHAR(b.datetime, 'MON') = 'JAN'
group by ohi.item_id) JanItems ) JanItemsWMaxAndMin WHERE CountItems = minItems or CountItems = maxItems`

`

Comment: Square brackets ( `[...]`) are invalid in an identifier in (standard) SQL  (and Oracle)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
with t as (
  SELECT i.item_id, sum(ohi.qty) as qty_sum 
    FROM order_has_item ohi 
   INNER JOIN orders o 
      ON o.order_id = ohi.order_order_id
   INNER JOIN item i 
      ON i.item_id = ohi.item_item_id
   WHERE o.datetime BETWEEN to_DATE('2018-12-15', 'yyyy-mm-dd') 
                        AND ADD_MONTHS(to_DATE('2018-12-15', 'yyyy-mm-dd') , 1)
   GROUP BY i.item_id
)
SELECT min(t.qty_sum) as min_sum,  
       max(t.qty_sum) as max_sum,
       min(t.item_id) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY t.qty_sum) as item_min,
       min(t.item_id) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY t.qty_sum) as item_max
  FROM t;
```

as you can see on demo it has the same result as answer before do.[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5f31e120a01858f807c6bda2e3781854)